# How to set spacing in Frangi filter for 3D stack of DICOM data

Tags: scikit-image, spacing, imaging, medical, medical-imaging

I am using the **Frangi filter** for **hepatic vessel segmentation**.
The problem is that that data are not isotropic [1,1,1].
I can do resampling. It creates more slices but it looses pixels and its not so precise.

I found, that maybe I can change it directly in the Frangi function (skimage function) in the script where the Hessian function is computed. But even then I don't know which values I should set up as **spacing**.

Because now I have some results, but they are not correct, because I am computing with squeeze image in z-direction.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By my reading of the code, currently it is not possible to use a different scale (sigma) for the different axes — we assume the same sigma is used for each axis. It should be possible to improve this in a future version. You can create a feature request at https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/new/. I suggest that you link back to this question when creating it.